# Moving a character in a java tiled game?

Tags: java, graphics, javafx

(Sorry for English, I am a French student, and a beginner in java)

I've seen the topics dealing with displacement characters in a Java game, but I still have two problems. I use a land 2d isometric, based on an array int[][] ( http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/91631150ex.png ) and a PaintComponent method :

If I want to move fluidly a character (soon to be represented by a real little personage with legs, arms and head), I do not know:

- How to move fluidly graphically the personage of one box to another in the table without affecting badly on the drawing
- How to move the character, even with JavaFX I can not give trajectories and movements in addition (AND legs moving character moves)

Thanks for reading and help :)

EDIT : I already heard of a TimeLine in JavaFX, but it just offers a basic translation, no?

Comment: Could you have your tiles as int[][] but have your character position defined as a float x, y rather than restricting them to the grid?  I may be misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes, actually my algorithm is a simple loop that reads the table tiles, and each iteration changes the value of x, y and z which are used by the polygon paintComponent to draw the tiles and characters, according to the values ​​in the table.
Therefore if I want to display an animation of moving fluid, it must be separated from the value in the table, otherwise the character will just disappear and then appear on the tile beside...

Answer (score 0):

First of i want to suggest you to go through the link of the graphical setting guide thoroughly i think you can overcome your problems
 http://www.ffxivcore.com/tutorials/article/6-ffxiv-graphical-settings-guide/

Comment: I probably misunderstood where you wanted to come, this page explains some aspects of graphics but do not provide information on how to proceed to make an animated character that moves in paintComponent ..!